# SUBSTRING function mysql

Tags: mysql

So I have a task to show all teachers who have their first 3 letters of name and surname the same.

I know I should use substring but I cant figure this out....

```
select SUBSTRING(name_surname,1,3)
from teacher
where
```

This is what I did so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First three letters of any value? [SUBSTR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring). As you know:

```
SUBSTR(surname, 1, 3)
```

Comparing two values of these for a WHERE filter?

```
WHERE SUBSTR(surname, 1, 3) = SUBSTR(given, 1, 3)
```